# Databricks Filesystem - %sh ls vs %fs ls

Tags: filesystems, databricks

I have some files located in `%sh ls` and I would want to move those files into the filesystem of databricks (make them visible in `%fs ls`).

Does any of you know what the difference is between `%sh ls` and `%fs ls`, and how do I move the files between them?

I know we can utilize `dbutils.fs.cp` to move files that are already in `%fs ls` location.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you are executing commands via `%sh`, they are executed on the driver node only, and showing the content on that machine.  When you're doing `%fs ls`, it's by default shows you content of DBFS (Databricks File System), but it can also show the local content if you add the `file://` prefix to the path.

You can copy or move files files as following:

1. Using `dbutils.fs.cp("file:///local-path", "dbfs-path")` (or `dbutils.fs.mv`)
2. By using so-called FUSE mount that mounts DBFS to local machines - you need to add the `/dbfs/` prefix to a path that you want to have on DBFS, like, `/dbfs/FileStore/....` (If you're using Community edition with DBR >= 7.x, then it may not work, so you have only the first method)

P.S. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html).

Comment: another great answer. any hints on where the (DevOps) repo files are located? i'm using %sh currently and can't see them

Comment: if you're talking about Repos files, then they are in the Workspace itself, they aren't the real files.

Comment: ah, i understand your previous comments better now.  excited to see where the features go with this use case; `import from my_module` will be very useful.

Comment: @d8aninja last year the feature called "Files in Repos" was released that allows to have python files imported as python modules: https://docs.databricks.com/repos/work-with-notebooks-other-files.html#work-with-python-and-r-modules