# In DataBricks how can I assign a variable a string value from external file?

Tags: python, databricks, configuration-files

In DataBricks I am trying to use an external file for my config variables. I created a CSV file and uploaded it to DBFS. Now I can only access it in the form of tables (DataFrames). How can I assign it to a variable as a string value? What are the other practices to get configuration variables in python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688728/databricks-filesystem-sh-ls-vs-fs-ls/66690084#66690084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read config file using `pandas` and initialize the variables accordingly with the columns present inside your csv config file

```
conf_df = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/mnt/<your path>')
date_conf = conf_df['date']
```

Since the config file is not gonna be significant enough to actually use it in conjuction with Spark , you can resort to `pandas`

Comment: `/dbfs/` won't work on the community edition